# How to iterate column ID independently in while loop SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In this example, salary and bonus, from different employee is mixed in while loop, which make the calculation invalid.

How to iterate each ID independently and do certain calculation based on that ID?

```
while (select count(*) from db.employee) > 0
begin   
    select top 1 ID, SALARY, [month] 
    from db.employee  
    order by [month] asc

    if deserve = yes
    begin
        set SALARY = SALARY + (bonus * 2)   
    end
end
```

This is not my script. I have complex script, that will take time to understand the objective. However, I mimic the logic to this simple idea. So later I can tweak my original script based on suggestion. The original one is [Iterate through tables and do calculation based on one column SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820935/iterate-through-tables-and-do-calculation-based-on-one-column-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment82666901_47820935)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways.

First I'm just curious why you don't just do a normal update?

```
update emp
set salary = emp.salary + (bonus * 2)
from employee emp
join bonuses bon on bon.employee_id = emp.employee_id
where bon.deserved = 1
```

Another way would be to use CURSOR, but people don't really like them because of their performance issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Another way would be to create a container to hold the employee count, then while loop through while the current itteration doesn't equal the count and grab the required employee on each loop, e.g.

```
declare @employeecount int = (select count(*) from employee)
declare @current int = 1

while @current <= @employeecount
begin

    declare @employeeid uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 employee_id from (select top (@current) * from employee order by employee_id asc) tmp order by employee_id desc)

    -- Grab Employee and run logic

set @current = @current + 1;
end
```

The bottom pretty much just does what CURSORS do, but I've noticed cursors do it better.

The one below is what I've recently taken to doing. I find it's just easier to follow along with.

```
declare @ids table (id uniqueidentifier)
insert into @ids
select employee_id
from employee

while (select count(*) from @ids) > 0
begin

    declare @employeeid uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 employee_id from @ids)

    -- Grab Employee and run logic

delete from @ids where id = @employeeid
end
```

Comment: I like last one, but it seems I will have some issues. Iterate is not on each ID, some bonus might be mixed between ID.

Comment: I like to do something similar to (select top 1 employee_id from (select top (@current) * from employee order by employee_id asc) order by employee_id desc). I made another way of doing it, which you might like and find easier to read in large code.

Comment: in selection `employee_id` is `ID` filed in my example. And in last line in `where` what `id` stand for

Comment: id is the column name is the table variable @ids